# Extract phone no and fax no from string python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string as below:

```
"""350 tel: (650) 725—9327 fax: (650) 723» 1882"""
```

I want to extract phone no and fax no differently in python.

So far thi is how I am finding phone numbers:

```
re.findall(r'[\+\(]?[1-9][0-9 .\-\(\)]{8,}[0-9 ]', string)
```

How can I find also the fax number?

Answer (score 2):

To get the tel and the fax for your given example you might use a positive lookbehind `(?<=` to assert that what is on the left is either tel or fax part.

[`(?<=(?:tel|fax): )\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[—»]\s*\d{4}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/F0j7CF/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=(?:tel|fax): )` Positive lookbehind to match either tel or fax followed by a colon and a whitespace
- `\(\d{3}\)` match an opening parenthesis, 3 digits and a closing parenthesis
- `\s*` Match zero or more times a whitespace character
- `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
- `[—»]` Match one of the specified characters using a character class
- `\s*` Match zero or more times a whitespace character
- `\d{4}\b` Match 4 digits followed by a word boundary

Instead of `[—»]\s*` you could also use [`\D+`](https://regex101.com/r/F0j7CF/2) to match not a digit one or more times.

For example:

```
import re
string = """350 tel: (650) 725—9327 fax: (650) 723» 1882"""
print(re.findall(r'(?<=(?:tel|fax): )\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[—»]\s*\d{4}\b', string))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OZXCZ57716)

Comment: Thanks for this nice explanation It was needed as I am naive in regex

Answer (score 1):

*If the format of the phones will be variable you can use this approach:*

```
import re
string = """350 tel: (650) 725—9327 fax: (650) 723» 1882"""
phone_regex  = re.match(".*tel:(.*)fax:(.*)",string)
phone , fax = [ re.sub("[^0-9]","",x) for x in phone_regex.groups() ]
```

Comment: "tel 6504629154  chipotle mexican grill inc fax 6504621252  2675 el camino real palo alto ca 94306 " My sring is something  like this so It it is taking fax = 6504621252267594306 and I want only 6504621252 How to resolve that